# PHP SQLSRV Insert Else Update

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm in the process of migrating a project from MySQL to MS SQL. This is much different than I'm used to because I'm coming from 1 MySQL table to a MS SQL View and Table. I wish I could stick with MySQL but this is out of my control.

I need to insert data else update data into the sql table. Here's my attempt and the error. Please help:

```
$serverName = "myserver";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"sqldatabasename", "UID"=>"myusername", "PWD"=>"youguysarethebest" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO CallSettings (Order_Number, ODetail_id, Serial_Id, AssignedPerson, Status, Comments, Customer_IPAddress, customer_assistance_name, customer_assistance_number, customer_assistance_email,networksettings, addressbook, accountcodes, installedprintdrivers) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?) ELSE UPDATE CallSettings SET (Order_Number= (?), ODetail_id= (?), Serial_Id= (?), AssignedPerson= (?), Status= (?), Comments= (?), Customer_IPAddress= (?), customer_assistance_name= (?), customer_assistance_number=(?), customer_assistance_email= (?), networksettings= (?), addressbook= (?), accountcodes= (?),     installedprintdrivers= (?))";

$params = array($Order_Number, $ODetail_id, $Serial_Id, $AssignedPerson, $Status, $Comments,         $Customer_IPAddress, $customer_assistance_name, $customer_assistance_number, $customer_assistance_email,         $networksettings, $addressbook, $accountcodes, $installedprintdrivers);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Error

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 07002 [SQLSTATE] => 07002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error ) )
```

Comment: `MySQL to SQL` is an incorrect statement you are going to `mssql`, mysql uses SQL. I'd guess `sqlsrv_query` requires 1 value per placeholder. You have one value per placeholder in the `insert` but then appear to be using the same for the `else` (I also assume the `else update` is valid mssql, not familiar with that).

Comment: If i just do an insert, it works fine. I need an insert else update statement. There's not a lot of posts about php and sqlsrv

Comment: It might be easier to migrate the data manually (export csv from MySQL and import into SQL Server)

Comment: So you need to increase the number of values... unless mssql has an emulation like PDO but I don't see how it'd know you meant for `?` 15 to map to placeholder 1.

Comment: I can export csv from MySQL and import into SQL Server but thats a manual process.

Comment: How do you decide which row to update (primary key or WHERE condition)?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because you are passing less parameters than  the expected (14 instead of 28).

You need parameters for all `?` marks in the query. You are passing parameters for the first 14 elements only (the update part has 14 more parameters, even if they are the same of the first part), so you need to repeat the parameter array in the query call (2 times the list of parameters) to pass all values.

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array_merge($params,$params));
```

Comment: I get the following error: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 156 [code] => 156 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '('. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '('. ) )